# Dragging point along vector with mouse

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been experimenting with trigonometry for the past few days, and came up with one of those neat stat pentagons you find in some games. ([**fiddle!**](http://jsfiddle.net/GrandonBroseph/62u8085k/))

**I'd really like to allow the vertices of the inner polygon to be draggable to change the stat values**. I have mouse functionality working well, but **what's the best way to drag a point on the line with the mouse?**

I've created a picture to visualize my problem; the red polygon is the "current" polygon, the pink lines represent the new polygon, the pink circle emphasizes the new point for the vertex, the blue line is the vector tangent, and **the green circle is the cursor.**

[image: Pentagon Diagram]

I've written a program which deals with vectors before, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this situation.

Here's some code (in the loop function):

```
for(var i = 0; i < innerPolygonKnobs.length; i ++){
    var knob = innerPolygonKnobs[i];
    distX = knob.x-mouse.x;
    distY = knob.y-mouse.y;
    distTotal = Math.sqrt(distX*distX + distY*distY);
    if(distTotal < 8){
        if(!knob.over)change = true;
        knob.over = true;
        if(mouse.down){
            // What goes here?
        }
    } else {
        if(knob.over)change = true;
        knob.over = false;
    }
}
if(change)redraw();
```

Thanks so much in advance! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will give you the closest point to the mouse on any given line:

```
// given a line defined like this
var line={x0:50,y0:50,x1:150,y1:150};

// calculate the closest point on the line to [x,y]
function getClosestPointOnLine(line,x,y) {
    //
    lerp=function(a,b,x){ return(a+x*(b-a)); };
    var dx=line.x1-line.x0;
    var dy=line.y1-line.y0;
    var t=((x-line.x0)*dx+(y-line.y0)*dy)/(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    t=Math.min(1,Math.max(0,t));
    var lineX=lerp(line.x0, line.x1, t);
    var lineY=lerp(line.y0, line.y1, t);
    return({x:lineX,y:lineY});
};
```

Then just redraw your inner polygon to connect to the point found above.

Interesting app...good luck with it!

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed! May I ask how the function works? I'm not too sure what `lerp` is supposed to do.

Comment: Sure! This function calculates the point on the line that is closest to the mouse. It does this by calculating a tangent line from the mouse to the line and determining how far that tangent line is along the original line. The "t" is that value from 0.00 to 1.00 (like a percent) representing how far the tangent point is along the original line. "Lerp" means "linear interpolation" and it's used to calculate the x & y which is "t" percent of the way from the beginning and ending of the line.  Cheers!

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense now. I just got the [program](http://s.codepen.io/GrandonBroseph/debug/NPOGdd) working, it runs perfectly! Thanks a ton for your help.