# Distance from X to edge of shape drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```html
<html>
<body style="margin:10px;">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
  
</body>
  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var centerX = 400;
      var centerY = 400;
      var radius = .5;

      context.beginPath(400,400);
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'blue';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 1;
      context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
      context.stroke();



      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(50, 250);
      context.bezierCurveTo(50, 250, 50, 250, 50, 250);
      context.bezierCurveTo(90, 210, 90, 210, 90, 210);
      context.bezierCurveTo(130, 90, 130, 90, 130, 90);
      context.bezierCurveTo(260, 240, 260, 240, 260, 240);
      context.bezierCurveTo(255, 400, 255, 400, 255, 400);

      context.closePath();
      context.lineWidth = 1;
      context.strokeStyle = 'green';
      context.stroke();
 
</script>
   
   
   
   
</html>
```

First time posting here but this website has helped me a lot with other grey areas I've had!

I want to determine the distance from a point on canvas to the edge of a shape. The shapes will be irregular, so for example if its a triangle I don't think the distance formula would work if it lands beyond an edge of a triangle.

I'm kinda bummed out because this might be the downfall of my project. Any open thoughts would be appreciated!

Thank you

EDIT: Here is an example of what I'm talking about, in this example I want to know how many pixels it is from co-ord 400,400 to the nearest point of the object. But For my project no matter where this dot is I want to be able to measure to the nearest point of the object.

I know this is a lot to ask but I thought I'd give it a shot!

Thanks for any replies in advance!

Comment: Are the shapes all polygons -- made from line segments?  When you say "distance" do you mean to the closest point on the shape or something else? If yes to both, you can test each line segment of the polygon and [find the least distance from the point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021887/dragging-point-along-vector-with-mouse/29023665#29023665).

Comment: The edge x,y coords will vary depending on the polygon and canvas methods being used....Can you post code sample?

Comment: As far as I know (a little rusty in all honesty), since Canvas uses raster (pixel) drawing, once you draw a shape it's forgotten, of course, you could compare each pixel color, but that would be costly. The best way would be to keep track of every shape you draw to the canvas and compare against those, as to the math behind that it really depends on your usage

Comment: Also this is outside the question, but an "open thought"; just because you hit a snag doesn't mean the project is dead, just spend some time thinking about the problem, and some formula or redesign will come to you (happens all the time), then you're back on track!

Comment: @KpTheConstructor updated for your viewing pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

The scope of this question is to much for me to write a solution. I will give a overview of how with a few limits added.

A shape is a set of arcs, lines, curves (cubic and quadratic), and rectangles that may or may not be joined. The distance will be the closest point on the line that defines each of these shapes, and will not include the line width. The shape is all at the same scale and orientation.

The best way is to use the distance to line function pointed out by MarkE (in his comment "[find the least distance from the point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021887/dragging-point-along-vector-with-mouse/29023665#29023665)") and convert all the path objects to lines. How finely you subdivide each curve will determine how accurate the position will be, straight lines don't need subdivision.  But assuming you are only after a pixel (the mouse resolution) it will not be too much processing for the code to do.

You can define the lines as sets of points. As you may have unjoined paths the sets of points will be in a two dimensional array.

```
var lines = [];
var currentLine = null;
function startLine(){
   if(currentLine.length > 0){
       currentLine = []; // new array
       lines.push(cuurentLine); // push onto the line array
    }
}
function moveToPoint(x,y){
   startLine();
   addPoint(x,y);
}
function addPoint(x,y){
   currentLine.push(x:x,y:y);
}
function closePath(){
   currentLine.push(currentLine[0]);
}
```

Then you can match all the render calls with calls to the above functions

At the most simple a set of lines

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x,y); // to save me time x and y are points of some coordinate.
ctx.lineTo(x,y);
ctx.lineTo(x,y);
ctx.lineTo(x,y);
ctx.closePath();
```

Should be matched with

```
startLine(); // you really only need moveToPoint
moveToPoint(x,y); 
addPoint(x,y);
addPoint(x,y);
addPoint(x,y);
closePath();
```

Your array should look like

```
// p represents a point {x :x,y: y}
lines [[p,p,p,p,p]]; // An array inside lines with 5 points. The last point is 
                     // back to the start
```

If you add another path

```
ctx.moveTo(x,y); // to save me time x and y are points of some coordinate.
ctx.lineTo(x,y);
ctx.lineTo(x,y);
ctx.lineTo(x,y); 
// note I did not close path
```

you must match it with

```
moveToPoint(x,y); 
addPoint(x,y);
addPoint(x,y);
addPoint(x,y);
```

The array will now look like

```
// p represents a point {x :x,y: y}
lines [[p,p,p,p,p],[p,p,p,p]]; // not second path is not closed and has one less point
```

and contain two paths.

You can then check using the line function (linked at top of answer) to find the point closest to the shape

```
function findclosestPoint(px,py){ // the point px,py
    var minDist = Infinity; 
    var pf = {x:0,y:0};  // the closest point
    for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i+=1){
        for(j = 0; j < lines[i].length-1; j+=1){
            var p = lines[i][j];
            var p1 = lines[i][j+1];
            // get closet point
            var cp = getClosestPointOnLine({x0 : p.x, y0 : p.y, x1 : p1.x, y1 : p1.y},px,py);
            // then get the distance.
            var x = cp.x - px;
            var y = cp.y - py;
            x *= x;
            y *= y;
            var dist = Math.sqrt(x + y);  

            // is it the closest?
            if(dist < minDist){
                minDist = dist; // yes remember this distance
                pf.x = cp.x;
                pf.y = cp.y;
            }
        }
    }
    return {dist : minDist, point : pf};
}
```

The for the shapes you have you just need to call that functions and you have the solution.

```
var closest = findclosestPoint(400,400);
console.log(closest.point) ;// >> {x:?,y:?}
console.log(closest.dist) ;// >> ? in pixels
```

To get it to work for arcs create a function that divides the arc into smaller line segments. The same for the bezier curve and cubic curves. Spacing points about 2 to 3 pixels apart should be plenty. The are plenty of examples for finding points on arcs and beziers in StackOverflow.

For a rectangle as an example

```
ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
```

Create a function to add the lines that define the rectangle.

```
function addRect(x,y,w,h)
    addPoint(x,y)  // rects start at top left  
    addPoint(x+w,y)  
    addPoint(x+w,y+h) 
    addPoint(x,y+h) 
    addPoint(x,y)  
}
```

Remember that fillrect and strokeRect start with moveTo so add the moveToPoint function call if needed.

Do the same for arc, and the bezier curves.

And that is all there is to it.

If you plan to have differing scales and rotations you will have to add those transformations when you add points to the lines array.

If you wish to include line width, you will have to create lines for each edge of the lines. This can be tricky for beziers, but again there are solutions to each sub problem in stackoverflow. Start with the basics and refine till you meet your goal.