# Range input on Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, slider

I'm trying to create a range slider on a canvas element that gives me back a value that I can then use to manipulate the canvas elements. It needs to be inside the canvas as it's for an html5 banner ad. I understand I can't insert DOM elements into the canvas so I'm wondering if there is a library or plugin for creating a range slider using canvas?

What I want to be able to do is manipulate the position of an image on the canvas using a range slider. i.e. as the slider moves to the right the image position moves to the left and vice versa. I know I can do this with an input slider but am having trouble creating a slider on the canvas itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Range Control is easy enough to create natively -- especially if your range control is horizontally or vertically aligned.

**To create a very simple horizontal range control**

Given these values for the range control:

- The starting position of the bar: `x,y`,
- The width of the bar: `width`,
- The height of the thumb: `height`,
- The current thumb position expressed as a percentage: `pct`.

Display the range control:

- Draw the range bar: A horizontal line between `[x,y]` and `[x+width, y]`.
- Draw the range thumb: A vertical line between `[x+width*pct, y-height/2]` and `[x+width*pct, y+height/2]`.

To set the thumb position:

1. Listen for `mousemove` events and get the current `mouseX` position.
2. Use the current mouse position to calculate the percentage that the mouse is between the start & end of the range's bar: `pct=(mouseX-x)/width` where mouseX is clamped between `x` & `x+width`.
3. Redisplay the range with it's newly calculated thumb percentage.

Use `pct` to calculate the range control value: `value=minValue+(maxValue-minValue)*pct`.

**Non axis-aligned range controls**

If your range control is not positioned horizontally or vertically you will need to calculate the closest point on the bar to the mouse. Then you must calculate the percentage distance that point is between the starting & ending points of the range's bar. This previous [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021887/dragging-point-along-vector-with-mouse/29023665#29023665) shows how to find the point on the line (line==range bar) closest to the current mouse position.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;

var range=makeRangeControl(50,40,200,25);
drawRangeControl(range);

canvas.onmousedown=(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
canvas.onmousemove=(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
canvas.onmouseup=(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
canvas.onmouseout=(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});


function makeRangeControl(x,y,width,height){
    var range={x:x,y:y,width:width,height:height};
    range.x1=range.x+range.width;
    range.y1=range.y;
    //
    range.pct=0.50;
    return(range);
}

function drawRangeControl(range){
    // clear the range control area
    
    // bar
    ctx.lineWidth=6;
    ctx.lineCap='round';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(range.x,range.y);
    ctx.lineTo(range.x1,range.y);
    ctx.strokeStyle='black';
    ctx.stroke();
    // thumb
    ctx.beginPath();
    var thumbX=range.x+range.width*range.pct;
    ctx.moveTo(thumbX,range.y-range.height/2);
    ctx.lineTo(thumbX,range.y+range.height/2);
    ctx.strokeStyle='rgba(255,0,0,0.25)';
    ctx.stroke();
    // legend
    ctx.fillStyle='blue';
    ctx.textAlign='center';
    ctx.textBaseline='top';
    ctx.font='10px arial';
    ctx.fillText(parseInt(range.pct*100)+'%',range.x+range.width/2,range.y-range.height/2-2);
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // get mouse position
  var mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  var my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // test for possible start of dragging
  isDown=(mx>range.x && mx<range.x+range.width && my>range.y-range.height/2 && my<range.y+range.height/2);
}

function handleMouseUpOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // stop dragging
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // get mouse position
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // set new thumb & redraw
  range.pct=Math.max(0,Math.min(1,(mouseX-range.x)/range.width));
  ctx.clearRect(range.x-12.5,range.y-range.height/2-15,range.width+25,range.height+20);
  drawRangeControl(range);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag the thumb on the range control</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Comment: Brilliant response, thank you very much. I now have to find a way to manipulate a bitmap based on the slider, which I think I will have to redraw using the value of the slider. ie. set up a variable `var leftPos = 0` 
then use `ctx.drawimage (img,leftPos,0);` 
to redraw the image based on the slider position. Let me know if you have any thoughts on that.

Comment: @JamiePatt. Yes, when the range control value changes (in mousemove) you clear the canvas and redraw the img with the appropriate `leftPos` offset and then redraw the range control. Good luck with your project! :-)